# R CMD check with an enviornment variable set

Tags: r

I want to run an R CMD check with an environment variable set. I want to do this on the command line (not in R, not with `devtools`). How do I do that?

The specific one I want to set is `_R_CHECK_DEPENDS_ONLY_=true` because of section [1.1.3.1 Suggested packages](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Suggested-packages) of "Writing R Extensions" seeming to suggest doing this.

Comment: R CMD CHECK is typically used on packages, not individual datasets. Are you building a package with the typical DESCRIPTION/NAMESPACE/code that R CMD CHECK can parse?

Comment: I don't build my packages from the command line, so I might be missing something, but in most shells you can do `export _R_CHECK_DEPENDS_ONLY_=true` (bash-like shells) or `setenv _R_CHECK_DEPENDS_ONLY_ true` (csh/tcsh) to set the envvar for the whole shell (including any child processes started from it such as your `R CMD check`), or you can do it for one execution only with `_R_CHECK_DEPENDS_ONLY_=true R CMD check ...`.

Comment: I tend to do what @r2evans shows here and just asssign it at the beginning of the the command-line I want to run.  You can also try editing your `~/.Renviron` and/or a site-wide `Renviron.site` or try one in the current directory -- R reads all.  However, I find altering the actual invocation cleanest because it makes you less likely to be 'surprised' when a shell or setup you use again still has the value set and alters behavior more silently.

Comment: I checked by opening R GUI at the CLI (on windows, with bash) and this works because `Sys.getenv("_R_CHECK_DEPENDS_ONLY_")` returns `[1] "true"` what's odd about this is that when I go do `R CMD CHECK` it says it rebuild by vignettes, but it absolutely cannot with out the suggested. The R in them literally check and calls `stop()` if they packages only in suggested are not there.

Comment: Use `R CMD check --no-vignettes`  (and possibly `--no-manual` unless you have working LaTex).

Comment: Sorry I was unclear. I'm saying it can't have rebuilt the vignetes with `_R_CHECK_DEPENDS_ONLY_` set (it needs the suggests packages, but the `R CMD CHECK --as-cran` result says that it did check that. Does `--as-cran` ignore environment variables or something?

Answer (score 2):

- You may add the key=value at `~/.R/check.Renviron`. The home directory (`~`) can be located by executing `Sys.getenv("R_USER")` on R. Refer the "Note" section of https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Startup.html
- Else, you may directly create an environment variable in your system. I hope it will work too. If you are on Windows then hit 'windows' button, type-in 'environment variable', and add a new environment variable as desired.

Comment: I'm using Windows and R can return any of 3 folders for ~/ at various times (so, yay, I have three copies of .Rprofile) so a better solution for me is to use their note (that you pointed to) and make a file named `R_chk_env.R` and then ran with `R_CHECK_ENVIRON=r_chk_env.R R CMD check --as-cran ...` even with that I see no indication that the environment was set correctly. Am I supposed to? Is there a way to know, when running checks?

Comment: Honestly I am not sure as I didn't face this situation. I would have played around with some environment variables intentionally to verify the effect. I believe this should work as per the official docs.